# Having access to Global variable in all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Probably not the best practice but for a quick prototype work I need this:

in a method in one controller I am assigning a value to a global variable like this:

```
@@globalVar = someValue
```

Now in the index method of another controller I want to have access to that variable but it gives me a `Uninitialized Class Variable"` error.

How can we do this?

Comment: based on your conversation, you should look into `session[:your_variable]` in order to save something for later for just 1 user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a value, that is accessible over various actions (user interactions with rails). That is done by using the `session` hash:

```
def one_action
  session[:global_value]=params[:value_to_remember]
  ...
end


def index_of_other_controller
  remembered_value = session[:global_value]
  ...
end
```

Comment: worked, thanks. So just a general question: using session in this scenario, it worked but is it also the correct way of doing it? or is it good enough type of coding for my prototype ?

Comment: session is intended for this kind of persistend data. See the documentation in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are denoted with a `$` in Ruby. Try `$globalVar = someValue`.

Comment: Hmmm it is still nil.  So something else is going on? otherwise it should have worked with $ ?

Comment: You can't persist data across requests in this way. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: not sure what you mean by persist, I just want to know what have they picked on the first tab - the value - and when they click on second tab I want to pass that as a value to my web-service.

Comment: Maybe I can also use flash[:myVar], Marked your answer as correct but still if you have better ideas please let me know. Thanks.